# Removing unmatched points from geocoded FeatureClass using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c#, geocoding, feature-class

I have geocoded some locations but I need to remove the unmatched locations that are in the resulting FeatureClass. How can I do this programmatically with C#? I am able to get the unmatched features but I can't seem to figure out how to actually remove them from the FeatureClass.

```
public static void RemoveUnmatchedFeatureFromFeatureClass(string workSpace, string featureClass)
    {
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory")) as IWorkspaceFactory;
        IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(workSpace, 0) as IFeatureWorkspace;
        IFeatureClass unMatchedFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(featureClass);

        IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
        queryFilter.WhereClause = "Status = 'U'";
        using (ComReleaser comReleaser = new ComReleaser())
        {
            IFeatureCursor newCursor = unMatchedFeatureClass.Search(queryFilter, false);
            IFeature unmatchedfeature = newCursor.NextFeature();

            while (unmatchedfeature != null)
            {
                //Remove feature

                unmatchedfeature = newCursor.NextFeature();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to delete a bunch of rows that fulfill  a query, in your case where `Status = 'U'` is to call the *DeleteSearchedRows* method on [ITable](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ITable.htm)